# WordPress: get custom field value before a post is updated

Tags: wordpress, hook, custom-fields

**What I want to do:**
In WordPress, when I edit the custom field value of a post, get the old value and the new value, and compare them.

**What I get now:**
I can only get the new value. I hook to the `pre_post_update` action, and I use `get_post_meta()` (and a bunch of related functions described in http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to get the value.

I also tried `get_post()`, which can return the old value of `post_content`, `post_title`, etc. But `get_post()` does not include the custom field values.

I think that at the time when the `pre_post_update` hook fires, the values have not been saved in the database yet, isn't it? The fact that I can get old value of post title, etc. proves it. Then there must be some way to get the old value of custom fields.

It is also welcomed if you can point out other ways to compare the old value and new value of custom fields.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to do this too - I was thinking of querying the database prior to the update of the new value in save_post query.  Seems a little redundant, so I'm still looking for a better method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare an old custom field with new, because when you update them it will rewritten also in the "wp_post_meta" table in db. You lose the old value for the new.

Answer (score 1):

**Pigi** has made the point. it will be over written. why not use too custom fields with two keys, old Key and new Key, and assign both old value to old key,new value to new key.

Comment: Like I said in the original post, I want to hook the action before the values are saved in the database. Are you saying there is no such hook in WordPress?

Comment: As far as I Know.there is not. maybe you can try access to the DB in your hook of pre_update_post function.

Comment: Manipulating database directly is not what I like (I'm a DB newbie >_<). I'll try to play with your two-key method, to see if it can fulfil my needs. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: :),,ok, if any issues, I am happy to help you further.